# Use SYSLINUX to boot from a separate device

Tags: linux, boot, sd-card, syslinux

I have a laptop with no harddrive that I'm booting from a modified persistent LiveCD thumbdrive, but performance is terrible due to the low speed of the thumbdrive.

I also have a class-10 SD card of similar size that I've been able to copy the appropriate files to, and even have it set up to be bootable. The only problem is that the laptop's BIOS doesn't support booting from the SD card reader.

I'd like to have the `SYSLINUX` bootloader on the thumbdrive have an entry to boot the SD card so I can take advantage of the higher data-transfer rate, but the documentation doesn't make any sense to me.

How do I construct an entry for the `syslinux.cfg` file so I can boot the SD card?